# jQuery: Prevent default form action and alert the user

Tags: jquery, form-submit

I have the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#ProjModelChoose").change(function() {
    $("#ProjModelChooseCOM").attr("name","form" + $(this).val());
    $("input[name='buyid']").attr("value", $(this).val());
});

$("#ProjModelChoose2").change(function() {
    $("#ProjModelChooseOEM").attr("name","form" + $(this).val());
    $("input[name='buyid']").attr("value", $(this).val());
});

$(".atcButton").click(function() {
    if($("select option:selected").val("Choose Your Projector Model")) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("Please choose a projector model");
    }
    });
});
</script>
```

The HTML:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr>
<span>Purchase today for: </span><h3 class="atcPrice">$192</h3>
<select name="chooseModelOEM" id="ProjModelChoose">
<option value="Choose Your Projector Model">Choose Your Projector Model</option>
<option value="126648">PLC-SU70</option>
<option value="126682">PLC-WXE45</option>
<option value="126684">PLC-WXE46</option>
<option value="126686">PLC-WXL46</option>
<option value="126717">PLC-XE40</option>
<option value="126719">PLC-XE45</option>
<option value="126795">PLC-XL40</option>
<option value="126797">PLC-XL45</option>
<option value="126998">PLC-XU73</option>
<option value="127000">PLC-XU74</option>
<option value="127006">PLC-XU83</option>
<option value="127008">PLC-XU84</option>
<option value="127010">PLC-XU86</option>
<option value="127012">PLC-XU87</option>
</select>
<form name="" action='someaction' method=post id="ProjModelChooseCOM" target="_blank"><input type='hidden' name='buyid' value=""><input type='hidden' name='c' value="1025622"><input type='hidden' name='n' value='5'><td class='text'><input name='add' id='add' size=4 value=1 class='qtyButton' border="0" ></td><td class='text'><input type="image" src="olp-atcbutbg.png" border='0' value='Add to Cart' alt='Add to Cart' class='atcButton'></td></form>
</tr>
</table>
```

Ok, so basically I am inserting the value from the selected option into the form when a user makes a selection from the drop down. That works fine. But if a user does not make a selection (Leaves the dropdown on the "Select your projector model") and tries to add the product to the cart, I want it to stop the form submit (it's dynamic so it's going to try to perform the action regardless) and display an alert. My code above does neither =/

Comment: you might want to look into having your select tag inside your form and checking for that value. this way, every thing is scoped under your form. I have done a http://jsfiddle.net/3NMDd/ feel free to edit it

Comment: I agree with @Yasky. It would make your HTML more valid and you wouldn't actually have to have any code to copy the value from the <select> to the hidden <input>. Forgot to mention this earlier.

Comment: I'll try the new suggestions tomorrow at work, but how do you mean I won't have to copy the value into the hidden input?

I only have one form submit and the value of the hidden field will still have to change depending on what is selected.

Comment: **UPDATE:** I have ran into 1 more bug. I have duplicated the form and submit to have different values. (basically have 2 different products on one page) and with the working code I am now using, it has broken again. I guess it is checking all of the dropdowns on the page, and I need it to be specific for each product.

The first drop down works perfectly. It's on the second dropdown where the issue arises. When the first drop down is at default selection and you make a new selection from second drop down, it still gives the alert. I have modified the code to do:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".atcButton").click(function() {
    if($("select option:selected").val() === "Choose Your Projector Model") {
        alert("Please choose a projector model");
        return false;
    }
});
```

You may also want to change your event handler from `$(".atcButton").click()` to `$("#ProjModelChooseCOM").submit()`.

**Update** Sorry I misunderstood the issue. Edited to address the value comparison issue.

Comment: Tried it, didn't work. Is the default option in a select list actually considered a "selection" by JS? Maybe that is the issue

Comment: Sorry. I missed that there were two issues. The above code should work a little better.

Comment: I tried your updated code and it still submits the form without an alert

Comment: Hmmm. I've just tested the above code in a test page, and it appears to work perfectly. Is there something we could be missing?

Comment: Very often if there is an error in the code, then the form will just submit without behaving as expected. Try checking your code with a JavaScript debugger like Firebug or the one built in to Chrome. This may help you discover where the issue is.

Comment: I put the <select> under the form and used your code again and it's working :) Thanks Horatio

Comment: I guess event.preventDefault(); was the issue? Weird

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".atcButton").click(function(event) {
    if($("select option:selected").val() === "Choose Your Projector Model") {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("Please choose a projector model");
        }
    });
});
```

I added "event" as an argument to the anonymous function called as a result of the click.

**Update:** I changed the value comparison code.

Comment: Actually, it didn't work, sorry. It displays the alert and cancels the form submit no matter what I select

Comment: Now it's back to my original issue, still submitting the form without an alert =/

Comment: I just tried it with == instead of === and it's still not working, ahhhh

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".atcButton").click(function(event) {
    if($("select option:selected").index() == 0) {
    alert("Please choose a projector model");
        event.preventDefault();     
    }
});
```

try this.